# What are the solutions for findByN1QL in SDK3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

When migrating from Couchbase SDK 2 to SDK 3 certain document formats seem to have been removed.
How can this format or an alternative output be used in Couchbase SDK 3 to handle the below-indicated API change?
This is one of the sample classes that used findByN1QL in the existing system.

```
private List<Document> getBspReconciledAgentTransactionDataList(
            BspReconciliationAgentTransactionLogicData transactionLogicData) {

        final String bucketName = getBucketName(repository);
        String query = getTransactionQueryStatement(transactionLogicData).toString();
        query = query.split(N1qlQueryUtil.WHERE)[NumberConstants.ONE];

        query = N1qlQueryUtil.selectOf(N1qlQueryUtil.metaOf(bucketName, "id", "_ID"),
                N1qlQueryUtil.metaOf(bucketName, "cas", "_CAS"), N1QlQueryConstants.COUNTRY_NAME,
                N1QlQueryConstants.COUNTRYCODE, N1QlQueryConstants.AIRLINECODE, N1QlQueryConstants.TRANSACTIONTYPE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.SUBMISSIONSTATUS, N1QlQueryConstants.RECONCILIATIONSTATUS,
                N1QlQueryConstants.IATA_CODE_CONST, N1QlQueryConstants.AGENT_CODE_CONST,
                N1QlQueryConstants.TRANSACTION_DATE_CONST, N1QlQueryConstants.DPC_PROCESSING_DATE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.E_TICKET_NO, N1QlQueryConstants.ORDER_ID, N1QlQueryConstants.PASSENGER_NAME,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CURRENCY, N1QlQueryConstants.DEBIT_AMOUNT_POSTED,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CREDIT_AMOUNT_POSTED, N1QlQueryConstants.DEBIT_AMOUNT_FROM_HOT_FILE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CREDIT_AMOUNT_FROM_HOT_FILE, N1QlQueryConstants.ACMADM_REF_ID,
                N1QlQueryConstants.DOCUMENT_ID) +

                N1qlQueryUtil.fromOf(bucketName)
                + N1qlQueryUtil.whereOf(N1QlQueryConstants.CLASS_DETAIL_DOCUMENT + query);

        return getCouchbaseOperations(repository).findByN1QL(couchbaseConfiguration.cluster().query(query),
            BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);

private <T, I extends Serializable> CouchbaseOperations getCouchbaseOperations(
            CouchbaseRepository<T, I> repository) {
        return repository.getOperations();
    }
```

**Error showing line "findByN1QL"**,

return getCouchbaseOperations(repository).**findByN1QL**(couchbaseConfiguration.cluster().query(query),
BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);

**What would be the best possible options?**

I have a solution to "findByN1QL" using cluster,

```
//      return getCouchbaseOperations(repository).findByN1QL(N1qlQuery.simple(query),
//              BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);
        return cluster.query(query).rowsAs(BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);
```

With this scenario not used "CouchbaseRepository".Used Cluster.

```
@Autowired
private Cluster cluster;

private List<Document> getBspReconciledAgentTransactionDataList(
            BspReconciliationAgentTransactionLogicData transactionLogicData) {

        final String bucketName = getBucketName(repository);
        String query = getTransactionQueryStatement(transactionLogicData).toString();
        query = query.split(N1qlQueryUtil.WHERE)[NumberConstants.ONE];

        query = N1qlQueryUtil.selectOf(N1qlQueryUtil.metaOf(bucketName, "id", "_ID"),
                N1qlQueryUtil.metaOf(bucketName, "cas", "_CAS"), N1QlQueryConstants.COUNTRY_NAME,
                N1QlQueryConstants.COUNTRYCODE, N1QlQueryConstants.AIRLINECODE, N1QlQueryConstants.TRANSACTIONTYPE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.SUBMISSIONSTATUS, N1QlQueryConstants.RECONCILIATIONSTATUS,
                N1QlQueryConstants.IATA_CODE_CONST, N1QlQueryConstants.AGENT_CODE_CONST,
                N1QlQueryConstants.TRANSACTION_DATE_CONST, N1QlQueryConstants.DPC_PROCESSING_DATE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.E_TICKET_NO, N1QlQueryConstants.ORDER_ID, N1QlQueryConstants.PASSENGER_NAME,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CURRENCY, N1QlQueryConstants.DEBIT_AMOUNT_POSTED,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CREDIT_AMOUNT_POSTED, N1QlQueryConstants.DEBIT_AMOUNT_FROM_HOT_FILE,
                N1QlQueryConstants.CREDIT_AMOUNT_FROM_HOT_FILE, N1QlQueryConstants.ACMADM_REF_ID,
                N1QlQueryConstants.DOCUMENT_ID) +

                N1qlQueryUtil.fromOf(bucketName)
                + N1qlQueryUtil.whereOf(N1QlQueryConstants.CLASS_DETAIL_DOCUMENT + query);

         return cluster.query(query).rowsAs(BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);
```

**Does it work or not? Does anyone have any idea about it?**

Comment: I found a reference about the findByN1QL method change to findByQuery when migrating from SDC 3.x to SDC 4.x. Could this change be used to migrate the suggested code? Any Suggestions?

(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.migrating.repository)

Comment: I have a solution to "findByN1QL" using cluster,

//  return getCouchbaseOperations(repository).findByN1QL(N1qlQuery.simple(query),
//    BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);
  return cluster.query(query).rowsAs(BSPReconciledDetailDocument.class);

Does it work or not? Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPEL expression in an @Query method in a repository interfaces as shown below (assuming the n1ql statement will return Persons).

```
@Query("#{[0]}")
List<Person> myN1ql(String n1qlString);
```